# insert a row of data from a data frame directly to a database in R

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc

I am able to insert a row into a database, value-by-value in R as follows

```
#connect
conn = odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server; Server=MyServerName; Database=MyDBName; Uid=IAMTubby; Pwd=abcd;")

#insert
myquery = "insert into MyTableName values('1234','M','6','3');"
res = sqlQuery(conn, myquery)
```

However, I would like to insert maybe the first row of my data frame directly into sql instead of segregating them into values. How can I do this?
Say, my data frame looks like the following, and is of the same schema as the database

```
> df[1,]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1 1234    M    6    3
```

EDIT : I tried sqlSave but my RStudio crashes when I execute the following code. Where am I going wrong?

Table creation code in SQL-Server

```
#table creation
use DBName

CREATE TABLE Persons
(
col1 varchar(255),
col2 varchar(255),
col3 varchar(255),
);
```

R glue code

```
#library
library("RODBC")

#connect
conn = odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server; Server=MyServer; Database=DBName; Uid=username; Pwd=abcd;")

#inserting a data frame
df = NULL
df$col1 = '1'
df$col2 = '2'
df$col3 = '3'
df = as.data.frame(df)
sqlSave(conn, df[1,], tablename = "Persons", append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`RODBC::sqlSave`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RODBC/docs/sqlUpdate)? It seems like you can accomplish this by setting `append = TRUE` in this function.

Comment: Try adding the argument `rownames=FALSE` in the `sqlSave()` command.

Answer (score 3):

OPTION 1: You could create the query dynamically like this:

```
df = data.frame(col1 = 1234, col2 = "M", col3 = 6, col4 = 3) 
myquery = paste0("insert into MyTableName values(", paste0("'", df[1,], "'", collapse = ", "), ");")
```

This will save the  following string in the object myquery:

```
 "insert into MyTableName values('1234', '1', '6', '3');"
```

OPTION 2:

As @nrussell commented you should also be able to use the sqlSave function in the RODBC package with:

```
sqlSave(conn, df[1,], tablename = "MyTableName", append = TRUE)
```

Comment: You have understood my question. But instead of appending df[1,1], df[1,2] etc and creating a string, I was wanting to know if there is a way to directly write df[1,] to the database. Something like insert into MyTableName df[1,] if my table in the database has the same schema(the 4 columns, col1, col2, col3, col4) as the data frame df